# No application found with flask sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to Flask and I'm trying to connect a local postgre database with python.

My code is below:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/flaskmovie'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.username

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello Flask"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
'No application found. Either work inside a view function or push'
RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.
```

I've read the documentation and tried different options such as:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db.init_app(app)
    return app
```

and running the following code in the python shell:

```
app = create_app()
app.app_context().push()
```

But i'm still getting the same error.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
with app.app_context():
    db.init_app(app)
```

See [here](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/contexts/) for more information.

Comment: I tried it, as well as the other options in the link. Still getting the same error. Not sure if it could be some issue with the database. :S